# How to hire freelance writers for my self-published RPG who will adhere to my canon?

Tags: game-design, publishing, indie-rpg

I'm in the early stages of writing my own tabletop RPG System/Setting. I plan to self-publish most likely, probably starting off just on *DriveThruRPG* and seeing how it goes from there.

And I'm looking to hire some additional writers—of both “*fluff*” and “*crunch*”—because as much as I might like to, I really don't think I can design it all myself. I mean, I don't think any game system out there has ever been a solo authorship, has it?

What online community would you recommend to post this kind of “Help Wanted” ad? Is there a better way of hiring freelancers of this type?

Please note that I am looking for freelancers, not collaborators. In the past, I've had someone express interest in collaborating with me on the game, only to then go in and try to change about half of all my ideas and remake it into something that **this individual** wanted it to be. Unsurprisingly, we went our separate ways due to creative differences. I **am** very anal and OCD (literally—I suffer from pretty severe Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder) about this setting… it's my baby, and I'm not really looking for notes or “constructive criticism” about how to improve the parts of it I already have. Those are set in stone.

I am looking for writers who can take this as canon, as gospel, and then **add on to it**—new locations, new characters, new powers—without retconning or changing anything that's already established. Basically, I'm specifically **not** looking for co-authors who want to write **with** me, but for freelance writers who I **pay** to write **for** me.

For Further Clarification:** I'm currently unpublished. I don't have any kind of “inside” industry connections. I'm looking for a way to get my foot in the door as far as hiring/networking with freelancers. Particularly, I'm looking for a place to do this **online**.

For example, I know where to go when I'm ready to start hiring illustrators for my game book. The Conceptart.org Forums. I just put up a Wanted ad, describing the price range I'm looking to pay and the kind of art I need, and **BAM!** the emails start pouring in.  Is there a similar place like this online for RPG freelance writers?*

Comment: This question appears off topic because it is asking for a resource to find writers.

Comment: I believe this is on topic for the site currently per http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/609/are-questions-about-publishing-rpgs-on-topic. Those dissenting may VTC and **take discussion to meta** as desired.

Comment: That's enough commenting on this question.  Open a meta question if there is debate about question validity.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a setting bible written yet? If not, is that something within your resources to create?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I have one, yes—I would estimate it is about 40% complete, maybe a little more.

Comment: This can be answered via experience (see the first answer) although I suspect that it's expiry date is long passed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think that this specific topic would be more fitting for [writing.se](https://writing.stackexchange.com/), possibly using [tag:scriptwriting] tag.

Comment: Questions about publishing RPGs are on topic, and while they might also fit other .se sites, they also are valid here.

Comment: @Akixkisu I think that, by following the diagram in this [meta answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/610/51851) of the linked meta question, this question can be answered by any person with experience about searching for someone to write about an existing content/story, not only specifically RPG. But I understand why it might still be valid here.

Comment: @Zoma How so? Writing RPGs has its venues and expertise tied to the field and navigating those venues - here, we have those insights to handle those.

Comment: @Akixkisu Actually this question is about finding someone to write, not about how to write, so I don't think this is that much tied to RPG specifically. I agree that the writing process might have peculiar expertise needed, but I don't think that finding a writer, even for RPG, is that much different for any other writing needs based on existing content.

Comment: @Zoma Whenever you look for a particular writer, you have to look at appropriate places and approach them. You may also succeed with ineffective methods and in generalist places. The answer that we have is just not exhaustive in that regard.

Answer (score 9):

### Introduction

The thoughts and opinions I provide below are based upon some basic experience with hiring talented creators for a few projects throughout the years, but more so in my own experience with finding work as a creative writer and designer.

### First thoughts

As gathered from your question, it is clear that your vision for the game is very important to you and that it is to be YOUR game. I would suggest putting effort into keeping this clarity up in future correspondence with potential writers, wherever you end up finding them. Should they get the wrong impression, your time will be wasted (both in explaining this to the writer and in speaking with them in the first place).

In short, keep up the clarity of what you want and, even more, what you don't want, as you continually search for and employ writers.

### Freelancer sites

There are a few sites and web services that aim towards connecting freelancers with potential employers. Depending on which service you choose, these could generate a lot of interested writers, albeit of varying skill.

**[Freelancer.org](https://www.freelancer.com/)** is one such site, where freelancers from a wide variety of fields can connect with employers. While a bit buggy and prone to some weird visual effects, this site is powerful, secure and has a free-to-use option. Posting a job offer here generates, in my experience, a lot of correspondence.

**[Fiverr](http://www.fiverr.com)** is another such service, but starts at the other end, so to speak. On Fiverr, creators in various fields post what kind of work they are willing to do for $5 (or, a fiver). In creating writing, the offers vary from "I'll write an entire chapter" to "I'll write 200 words", depending on the writer and, often, their skill and reputation.

### Forums and communities

It is my experience that talented, creative writers can be found on forums and communities, bassed upon their interest, of course. I would suggest visiting various RPG forums (such as [Roleplayer Guild](http://www.roleplayerguild.com/)) and write a post about your project in some detail there (be very clear on the part about "your vision, your game"). While probably not as direct in finding a lot of Creative Writers as the Freelancer sites, the Writers you do find will probably have a greater understanding of writing for RPGs.

#### Disclaimer

*I am not endorsed in any way by the sites that I have mentioned above, nor have I been encouraged in any way to mention them here, or anywhere else. The sites I have mentioned are examples of sites that I, myself, have found useful in similar projects.*

Comment: Thanks, Gunnar. This sounds _somewhat_ helpful. [Roleplayer Guild](http://www.roleplayerguild.com/) could be a good place to post. I'm not so sure about [Fiverr](https://www.fiverr.com/) though, lol. Generic creative writing experience is fine and all, but people with experience specifically in writing for RPGs is much better, especially considering I need “_crunch_” as well as “_fluff_”… your average creative writing freelancer won't even know what that _means_, no less how to do it. We'll have to see how things go…